# How to rewrite url in apache htaccess for angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The htaccess I'm using is as follow

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -U
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-U
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ #/$1 [L]
```

On my localhost, when I'm simply typing localhost/ it's redirecting to localhost/home and my angular app is running perfectly. But when I'm directly typing the url  localhost/home it's throwing 404. 
I need to rewrite it as localhost/#/home

In my angular app, in index.html header, I've added  and $locationProvider.html5mode(true), html5 mode is working, but only problem is when refreshing browser...

Thank in advance everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this issue in my project with working on my VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular"
    ServerName  zeyton.dev
    ServerAlias www.zeyton.dev
    DirectoryIndex index.html
  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```