# Offline html5 mode AngularJS with Workbox ServiceWorker

Tags: angularjs, html, offline, workbox

We have an angularjs app that is served with nodejs and have workbox for serviceworker. Everything works fine with hashed version even offline (when killing the node express). Lets say we have this url

```
http://localhost:3000/#/form/1
```

and when its offline or node isnt running, it still loads the page because it is cached by serviceworker.

We decided not to use hash anymore and switch to html5 mode, now instead of hashed url we now have this

```
http://localhost:3000/form/1
```

This url wont work if directly browsed or reloaded and only works if clicked from the root

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Is this an AngularJS issue? Workbox? or this is an expected behaviour?
Thanks

** UPDATE **
This is different from [AngularJS routing 404 error with HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271461/angularjs-routing-404-error-with-html5-mode) we already solved this with express:

`app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
       res.sendfile('./server/public/index.html');`

The error is when its offline.

Comment: Did you set the Basepath?

Comment: Yes with <base href="/">

Comment: Did it work for you? we have a legacy angularjs app and we need to convert it to PWA do I was doing some research and found that